# How can I increase security on my portal?

Tags: networking, security

I have a series of routers that I want to have open (no pre shared keys/passwords or MAC filtering). I currently run [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) on all of them and use [WifiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/) to force people to login when connecting.

Without limiting access to the network, what things could I do to increase security?

Answer (score 1):

Run a web filter of some kind (I recommend [untangle](http://www.untangle.com)).  Blocking access to sites that promote illegal activity, pornography, etc will help keep things secure.

Comment: Would you say something like OpenDNS' filtering suffice?

Comment: Sure!  dd-wrt supports OpenDNS very well, actually.